# JAVA-LIBGDX How to set up correctly a scrollPane

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scrollpane

I am trying to add to my game a less sliding menu(left and right) at the bottom of the screen.
My problem is that I can not adjust the table at the bottom of the screen, this is my code:

```
   private void initUI() {
  // inizializzazione dello stage
  stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4));
  Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/uiskin.json"));
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

  // inizializzazione della tabella 
  container = new Table();
  container.setFillParent(true);
  stage.addActor(container);

  Table table = new Table();
  table.debug();

  final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(table, skin);
  scroll.setFillParent(true);

  InputListener stopTouchDown = new InputListener() {
     public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        event.stop();
        return false;
     }         
  };

  table.pad(20).defaults().expandY().space(5);

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

     table.row();
     TextButton button = new TextButton(i + "dos", skin);
     table.add(button);
     button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked (InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
           System.out.println("click " + x + ", " + y);
        }
     });
  }      

  container.add(scroll).expandY().fill().colspan(1);
  container.row().space(10).padBottom(10);
```

}

```
render(){
  Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4); 
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
  stage.draw();
  stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
  Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

}

In this way I can split the screen into 2 parts (top and bottom), but the input is not correct: to activate the first button I have to press the top of the screen but the buttom is "designed" at the bottom.

How i can create a table with a scrollpane in the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

There seems some misunderstanding of the viewport, table and how to use them:

Use one `Viewport` for your rendering your total screen. Split the screen up by using a   `Table`. Hence change the first line in `initUI` to

`stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));` (remove the /4)

and adjust your render method to something like:

```
 @Override
 public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
 }
```

Clear your color buffer, to make sure that animations, or button-press operations are drawed correctly. Do not set `stage` as `InputProcessor` every frame call. Once this is done in `initUI` it is ok.

To the size of the Table: I assume that the table does not match the containing elements. Hence everytime you add a button with `table.add(button)` add the information about its height and width with `table.add(button).height(...).width(...)`. Then the Table and the corresponding Scroll pane is adjusted right.

Currently I only see that `container` contains the `scroll` object that fills its parent that fills the whole screen. So make sure to add a further table to the container after you add the `scroll` to the `container` after `container.row().space(10).padBottom(10);`. This table will be drawn below the scroll pane.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU, i have done, this is my new code:

```
    // inizializzazione dello stage
    stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH,Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT/4));
    Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/uiskin.json"));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    // inizializzazione della tabella 
    container = new Table();
    container.setFillParent(true);
    container.bottom();
    stage.addActor(container);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.debug();
    table.bottom();

    final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(table, skin);
    //scroll.setFillParent(true);
    scroll.setupFadeScrollBars(0f, 0f);

    InputListener stopTouchDown = new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            event.stop();
            return false;
        }           
    };

    table.pad(20).defaults().space(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        TextButton button = new TextButton(i + "dos", skin);
        table.add(button).height(scroll.getHeight()).width(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH/8);
        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked (InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                System.out.println("click " + x + ", " + y);
            }
        });
    }       
    container.bottom();
    container.add(scroll).height(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);//.expandY().fill().colspan(1);
    container.row().space(10).padBottom(10);
```